# Change directory in Cypress using cy.exec()

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

Working with cypress to run a different folder's python script. but I guess the directory is not changing perfectly.

```
gotoPythonProject() {
 cy.exec("cd /Users/**/Desktop/project/");
 cy.exec("ls"); // which does not reflect the files of project that's been changed
 cy.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As with many CI tools it is normal behavior that every command starts in a fresh scope. This way a command is unaffected by the state of a previous one.

There are two practical solutions to this case:

1. Combine your commands using `&&`. For example:

```
cy.exec("cd .. && pwd");
```

2. Call a bash script. For example: `cy.exec("test_me.sh");`, your bash script would than look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
pwd
```